# readline() method of bufferedreader(socket.getinputstream) not waiting for input from client

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, bufferedreader

I'm developing an E-voting system using java. The client sends a number that represents a requested method. The run() method of the server thread then waits for input from the socket according to the sent number. The server reads input normally for the first client request however i get the following exception from the server:

> Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For
>   input string: "test"  at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)    at
>   ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:139)

Then the thread is terminated abnormally (i concluded that because when i try to perform another operation from the same client GUI i get a SocketException: Socket is closed). The user = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()); should wait for another integer to be sent by the client but its not. Its reading the last string sent. (Im using BufferedReader)

here is the run method of the serverthread:

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        int user = -1;
        // while ((user = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine())) != -1) {

        try {
            user = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Command Error");
        }

        switch (user) {
        case 1:
            try {
                String username = in.readLine();
                String password = in.readLine();
                int cid = -1;
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(
                        "SELECT UUID FROM user_acc WHERE UUID IN (SELECT CID FROM candidate) AND username = '"
                                + username + "';");

                if (Security.Authenticate(username, password) && !username.equals("") && !password.equals(""))
                    out.println("true");
                else {
                    out.println("false");
                //  in.reset();
                    break;
                }
                if (rs.next()) {
                    cid = rs.getInt(1);

                    String inetAddress = clientSocket.getInetAddress().toString().substring(1);
                    stmt.executeUpdate(
                            "UPDATE candidate SET ipadd = '" + inetAddress + "' WHERE CID = " + cid + ";");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Writing in Sign in Error");
            } catch (UserNotExistingException e) {

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            try {
                String username = in.readLine();
                String name = in.readLine();
                String password = in.readLine();
                String email = in.readLine();
                String conf = in.readLine();
                if (Security.signUp(username, name, email, password, conf))
                    out.println("true");
                else
                    out.println("false");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Reading in Sign Up Error");
            } catch (UsernameEmailExistsException e) {
                System.out.println("Email Exists");
                out.println("false");
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            try {
                String email = in.readLine();
                String code;
                if (Security.forgotPass(email)) {
                    out.println("true");
                    code = in.readLine();
                } else {
                    out.println("false");
                    break;
                }

                if (Security.checkCode(code, email))
                    out.println("true");
                else {
                    out.println("false");
                    break;
                }
                String newpass = in.readLine();
                String conf = in.readLine();
                String username = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < email.length(); i++)
                    if (email.charAt(i) == '@')
                        break;
                    else
                        username += email.charAt(i);

                if (Security.forceChangePassword(username, newpass, conf)) {
                    out.println("true");
                } else
                    out.println("false");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Reading in Forget Pass Error");
            }
            break;

        case 4:
            try {
                int CID = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()), userID = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                try {
                    if (nominate(CID, userID))
                        out.println("true");
                    else
                        out.println("false");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | UserNotExistingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case 5:
            try {
                int uid = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                String candname = in.readLine();
                if (vote(candname, uid))
                    out.println("true");
                else
                    out.println("false");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case 6:

            break;

        case 7:
            try {
                String text = in.readLine();
                int UID = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                int CID = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                if (postComment(text, UID, CID))
                    out.println("true");
                else
                    out.println("false");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case 10:
            try {
                String username = in.readLine();
                String oldPass = in.readLine();
                String newPass = in.readLine();
                String conf = in.readLine();
                if (Security.changePass(username, oldPass, newPass, conf))
                    out.println("true");
                else
                    out.println("false");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case 11:
            try {
                int CID = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ipadd FROM candidate WHERE CID = " + CID + ";");
                if (rs.next())
                    out.println(rs.getString(1));
                int port = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                out.write(port);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Here are my Client methods (in case the problem lies in them):

```
public class Client {
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private final int PORT_NUM = 4373;
    private static DataOutputStream p2pout;
    private String IP;

    public Client(String IP) throws IOException {
        this.IP = IP;
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket(IP, PORT_NUM);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot connect to the server, try again later.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void sendCommand(int com) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println(com + "");
        out.close();
        in.close();
    }

    public static boolean SignIn(String Username, String password) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println(1);
        out.println(Username);
        out.println(password + "\n");
        String reply = in.readLine();
        out.close();
        in.close();
        if (reply.equals("true"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static boolean SignUp(String Username, String name, String email, String password, String conf)
            throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println(2);
        out.println(Username);
        out.println(name);
        out.println(password);
        out.println(email);
        out.println(conf);
        String reply = in.readLine();
        out.close();
        in.close();
        if (reply.equals("true"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static boolean ForgetPass(String email) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println(3);
        out.println(email);
        String reply = in.readLine();
        if (reply.equals("true"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static boolean ForgetPass2(String code) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println(3);
        out.println(code);
        String reply = in.readLine();
        if (reply.equals("true"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static boolean ForgetPass3(String newpass, String conf) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println(newpass);
        out.println(conf);
        String reply = in.readLine();
        out.close();
        in.close();
        if (reply.equals("true"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static boolean nominate(int CID, int UserID) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println(4);
        out.println(CID + "");
        out.println(UserID + "");
        String reply = in.readLine();
        out.close();
        in.close();
        if (reply.equals("true"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static boolean vote(int cid, int UID) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println(5);
        out.println(cid);
        out.println("" + UID);
        String reply = in.readLine();
        out.close();
        in.close();
        if (reply.equals("true"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static boolean postcomment(int CID, String text, int UID) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println(7);
        out.println(text + "");
        out.println(UID + "");
        out.println(CID + "");
        String reply = in.readLine();
        out.close();
        in.close();
        if (reply.equals("true"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static boolean Changepass(String Username, String oldpass, String newpass, String conf) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println(10);
        out.println(Username);
        out.println(oldpass);
        out.println(newpass);
        out.println(conf);
        String reply = in.readLine();
        out.close();
        in.close();
        if (reply.equals("true"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public String getIPAddress(int cid) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println(11);
        out.println(cid + "");
        String inetAddress = in.readLine();
        out.close();
        in.close();
        return inetAddress;
    }

    public int getServerChatPort() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        int port = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        out.close();
        in.close();
        return port;
    }

    public static void connectionListener(String inetadd) {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(0);
            Socket clientSocket = ss.accept();
            out.println(ss.getLocalPort() + "");
            Socket candSock = ss.accept();
            ChatListener cl = new ChatListener(candSock);
            cl.start();
            out.close();
            in.close();
            while (true) {
                if (ChatListener.flag == 1)
                    cl.display();
                // ^^ Displayed in GUI
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public Socket chatConnect(String inetAdd) {
        Socket soc = null;
        try {
            int port = getServerChatPort();
            soc = new Socket(inetAdd, port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return soc;
    }

    public void send(String m) {

        try {
            p2pout.writeChars(m);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is invalid input, or invalid input handling. Nothing whatsoever to do with 'not waiting for input from client'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of problem is the socket close after each operation. Well the code close the output stream connected to the socket but closing the stream returned from `getOutputStream()` closes the associated socket as well.

The subsequent client send attempt fails because the socket is closed and the server fails because the receive operation (`readLine()`) is interrupted and no data is received.

Try to keep the client output stream open. You can create an class attribute like for Socket or whatever.

Comment: I removed all the in.close() and out.close() and still face the same problem

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "test"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:136)
The test is the last string sent to the server before the case ends and the loops restarts

Comment: Ok, does the client still throws an exception `SocketException: Socket is closed` ? And could you print out the received data at server side?